# Código dá erro de document.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, array

```
    Uncaught TypeError: document.getELementById is not a function
    at inserindoValores (desafio-array.html:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (desafio-array.html:48)
inserindoValores @ desafio-array.html:17
onclick @ desafio-array.html:48
```

E aí, pessu? Será que alguém poderia me ajudar a visualizar o que está errado no meu código? Essa mensagem fica aparecendo quando tento imputar um novo valor.

O código é esse:

```
<script>

      var objetos = ['Cadeira', 'Impressora', 'Garfo'];



      function inserindoValores(valor){

      var novoObjeto = document.getELementById('resultado').value;

        if (valor === 'adiciona') {

            if(novoObjeto === ''){
              alert('Informe um valor válido')
            } else{
              if (objetos.indexOf(novoObjeto)) {
              alert('Objeto já foi adicionado');
              } else {
                objetos.push(novoObjeto);
                console.log(objetos);
                document.getELementById('resultado').value = '';
              }
            }

        } else if (valor === 'ordena'){
          objetos.sort();
          console.log(objetos);
        }

      };


    </script>

    </head>

  <body style="padding: 50px 50px">

    <input type="text" name="desafio" placeholder="Digite um objeto:" id="resultado">
    <button type="submit" onclick="inserindoValores('adiciona')">Adicionar</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="inserindoValores('ordena')">Ordenar</button>


  </body>   

</html>
```

Muuuito obrigada desde já! Estou começando a aprender JS e levando 7x0 até agora hsauhsauh

Comment: Mari, javascript é case sensitive e você escreveu ```getELementById``` , percebe que o L está maiúsculo, deixe em em minúsculo: ```getElementById```

Answer (score 1):

O Javascript é uma linguagem *case sensitive*, isso significa que ele diferencia caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos. Em seu código você escreveu `getELementById` com o L maiúsculo, quando o correto é minúsculos. Tente o seguinte código:

```
document.getElementById('resultado').value
```

Comment: Nossa, galera! Reaal, nem tinha visto que tinha colocado o L maiúsculo.. Muito obrigadaaa!

Comment: Vixe, mas ainda não funciona. Dá esse erro:desafio-array.html:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at inserindoValores (desafio-array.html:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (desafio-array.html:48)

Comment: Não consegui simular esse novo erro, talvez você tenha alguma diferença no seu código atual e no postado na pergunta, consulte esse [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_assignment_left-hand_side) para saber mais sobre esse erro, caso ele não ajude, talvez seja interessante criar uma nova pergunta para ele com todo o seu código atual.

Comment: Acabei de refazer, eu tinha inserido um elemento, mas retirei e esse erro deixou de acontecer, mas agora independentemente do que eu escreva ele sempre leva a 'Objeto já foi adicionado'.

Comment: Isso acontece por conta da linha `if (objetos.indexOf(novoObjeto))`,  a forma correta de comparar o resultado de um `indexOf` é deste modo `if (objetos.indexOf(novoObjeto) >= 0)`

Comment: SIMMM consegui chegar nessa conclusão sozinha ainda agora e FUNCIONOUUU, feliz dmais ahahha brigada, mauricio!!